# Prevent MainActivity viewmodel recreation after launching intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-notifications, deep-linking

I'm using Jetpack compose and triger jetpack compose deep link when user clicks on a notification.
so this is how I create a notification when I receive it and user is in app:

```
class NotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {


    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {

        message.notification?.let { notification ->
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo)
                .setContentTitle(notification.title)
                .setContentText(notification.body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT).apply {
                    message.data["category"]?.let { category ->
                        this.setContentIntent(notificationDeepLinkHandler(category = category))
                    }
                }
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
                notify(1, builder.build())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

everything works, but it causes MainActivity recreation and it is bad because this is my MainActivity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        intent.extras?.getString("category")?.let {
            notificationDeepLinkHandler(it)
        }
        createNotificationChannel()
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = viewModel.destination) {
                    landingNavBuilder(navController = navController)
                    appNavBuilder()
                AuthenticationHandler(
                    navController = navController,
                    isUserAuthenticated = viewModel.isUserAuthenticated
                )
                SplashScreen()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As indicated, I have a composable `SplashScreen()`, which appears whenever the user opens the app and will disappear after 2 seconds. It has its own view model and is shown only once. But since launching a new intent will cause the view model to get destroyed, it appears again. How can I solve it?

The Approaches like setting the flag to "SingleInstance", "SingleTask", etc., is not helping.

```
  <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name=".main.presentation.activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:host="deeplink" android:scheme="myapp" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I tried to change the behaviour by the help of setting activity launch mode flags but it didn't help.